# Stuck with trying to show tictactoe values out of mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a tictactoe game with php and mysql. It should be played by 2 players from different systems. So I have a table in mysql with a column id which goes from 1-9 and a column tictac which has a value X or O or NULL. Put a x or o in the database is working but retrieving a X or O out of the table and show it on the screen is not working. I have a config file, a class.tictactoe.php, class.game.php and an index.php. The DB connection should be in the class.tictactoe.php but I don't know how.

I am having the most trouble with this part:

```
function displayGame()
{

    if (!$this->isOver())
    {
        echo "<div id=\"board\">";
        $i=1;
        for ($x = 0; $x < 3; $x++)
        {
            for ($y = 0; $y < 3; $y++)
            {
                require('config.inc.php');

                $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$db_name;host=$db_host",
                    $db_user, $db_pass,
                    [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);


                echo "<div id=\"$i\" class=\"board_cell\">";
                $i++;
                $query = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tictactoe WHERE value IS NOT NULL and id = ?');
                if ($this->board[$x][$y])
                    $query->execute([$lookup[$key]]);
                echo "<p>\"{$this->board[$x][$y]}\"</p>";
            else
                {
                    echo "<select name=\"{$x}_{$y}\">
                                <option value=\"\"></option>
                                <option value=\"{$this->player}\">{$this->player}</option>
                            </select>";
                }

                echo "</div>";
            }

            echo "<div class=\"break\"></div>";
        }

        echo "
                <p align=\"center\">
                           <input type=\"submit\" name=\"move\" value=\"Take Turn\" /><br/>
                    <b>It's player {$this->player}'s turn.</b></p>
            </div>";
    }
    else
    {

        if ($this->isOver() != "Tie")
            echo successMsg("Congratulations player " . $this->isOver() . ", you've won the game!");
        else if ($this->isOver() == "Tie")
            echo errorMsg("Whoops! Looks like you've had a tie game. Want to try again?");

        session_destroy();

        echo "<p align=\"center\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"newgame\" value=\"New Game\" /></p>";
    }
}

function move($postdata)
{

    if ($this->isOver())
        return;
    require('config.inc.php');

    $db = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$db_name;host=$db_host",
        $db_user, $db_pass,
        [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);

    $postdata = array_unique($postdata);
    $lookup = ['0_0'=>1, '0_1'=>2, '0_2'=>3, '1_0'=>4, '1_1'=>5, '1_2'=>6,
               '2_0'=>7, '2_1'=>8, '2_2'=>9];
    $query = $db->prepare('UPDATE tictactoe SET tictac = ? WHERE id = ?');

    foreach ($postdata as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($value!=$this->player) continue;
        $query->execute([$this->player, $lookup[$key]]);
        if ($value == $this->player)
        {
            $coords = explode("_", $key);
            $this->board[$coords[0]][$coords[1]] = $this->player;

            if ($this->player == "X")
                $this->player = "O";
            else
                $this->player = "X";

            $this->totalMoves++;
        }
    }

    if ($this->isOver())
        return;
}
```

The indentation might be wrong.

Comment: Use `value IS NOT NULL` instead of `!=`

Comment: I'm going to guess that this is supposed to be a part of a class with the `$this` variables. I'd suggest instead of loading the config file every time, load it within a `__construct()` function, and then you can save the db connection to a class variable.